# Dealing with zero-inflation if the data are not count data type

Tags: regression, modeling, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

In the literature I found that for the count data with a lot of zeros so-called zero-inflated distributions (models) and so-called hurdle-at-zero distributions (models) could be used. The differences between those two are well described on stackexchange

[What is the difference between zero-inflated and hurdle distributions (models)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81457/what-is-the-difference-between-zero-inflated-and-hurdle-distributions-models)

But what kind of models could be used if the data are not count data type (positive integer) but still zero inflated? Like for example exploring the coverage (%) of lichens on pre-defined part of tree trunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're still called "zero-inflated" models when modifying continuous distributions; there's [zero-inflated gamma](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=zero-inflated+gamma), zero-inflated lognormal, and so on.

For continuous proportions such as you describe, a [zero-inflated beta](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=zero+inflated+beta) model might be used (though it's not the only possibility, it's probably the most common by some distance).

If 100% coverage in that predefined part is possible, you might instead use 0-1 inflated beta models (sometimes called 0-and-1 inflated beta models; the search above finds some links for these as well), or if some other density between 0 and 1 is more suitable, some other form of 0-1-inflated continuous model.

Comment: Thank you. I also found out that it is possible to produce mixed effect models for zero-inflated data with R package glmmADMB. Instructions are available here: http://glmmadmb.r-forge.r-project.org/glmmADMB.pdf