# Implementing a hurdle/Zero-inflated Poisson model in R with right-censored count data

Tags: zero-inflation, tobit-regression

I'm trying to fit a hurdle/zero-inflated (I haven't decided yet) model on microbiological water quality data that is also right-censored: either the water sample is contaminated with bacteria or not, and if contaminated, the number of colonies can go from 1 to 99 and "more than 100" (because it was not possible to count the number of colonies beyond 100 - often referred in microbiology as "TNTC = too numerous to count").

If I refer to the data example taken by Kleiber and Zeileis (https://www.statistik.uni-dortmund.de/useR-2008/slides/Kleiber+Zeileis.pdf) I'm in a situation where the "number of visits to the physician" is censored to let's say "30 visits or more".

Is there a way to combine a hurdle or zero-inflated model (from the package pscl for example) with this right censored data distribution ? A sort or combined hurdle / ZIP + tobit model ??

Thanks a lot for your help
Lily

Comment: What do you intend to do with the model after you fit it to the data? How frequent are the right-censored counts among the contaminated samples?

Comment: I want to find predictors of water contamination amongst various other variables (watersource, pH, etc...). There are 36 right censored counts out of 445, and 256 values at 0.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't forget that a large number of 0 values does not necessarily require a zero-inflated or hurdle model. If you have a similarly large number of cases whose predictor-variable values would be associated with low probability of contamination then your data might not be zero-inflated at all. For deciding between zero-inflated and hurdle models, don't miss [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/81457/28500).

Second, if you do choose to use a hurdle model for the zeros then I understand that these are often fit in a two-step process: first the zero/positive dichotomous model and then the positive counts. In that case, after the zero/positive fit you would only have to deal with the right-censoring beyond 100 colonies in the second step, separately.

Third, the [`VGAM` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=VGAM) in R includes a `cens.poisson` family function for censored count data, either or both right- or left-censored. Its handling of censoring is based on the `survival` package, so the outcome variable has to be a survival object with both the counts and a censoring indicator. I haven't used it and there may be some tricks in formatting data to take advantage of this defined family function; examine its help page for examples of how to use it properly.

Finally, you could do your own maximization of the likelihood function for a zero-inflated Poisson model with right censoring. I happened to find the formula in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257142544_Zero-Inflated_Poisson_Regression_Models_with_Right_Censored_Count_Data). The [`maxLik` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=maxLik) provides tools for such a purpose, although I haven't used it myself.