# Alternate approach to modeling count data with many zeroes

Tags: binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution, count-data

One approach to modeling count data with many zeroes, if I understand correctly, is to use a zero-inflated *Poisson distribution*.

I read about an alternate (to using the zero-inflated *Poisson distribution*) approach that I am looking for feedback on and insight into, in part because I cannot remember where I read it.

I am considering this alternate because - at least in the software I am using (`lme4::lmer()` in `R`) - it is significantly harder to carry out the zero-inflated Poisson distribution approach than the proposed alternate approach.

The approach, in cases where there are many zeroes, is to run two separate models:

- one for whether the outcome is `0` or `1` (so a *binomial distribution*)
- one for - if the outcome is greater than `0` - what the number is (so a *Poisson distribution*)

I think for both, the predictor variables are exponentiated / the log of the outcome is used (if I understand how log link functions work).

**Does this two-step approach sound like a reasonable approach to modeling such data?**

In the case that data with many zeroes can be identified through a histogram, here is one of the response variables in my specific use case.

[image: histogram of dv]

Comment: the mixture distribution you describe *is* a 0-inflated Poisson probability model.

Comment: Oh. Does my approach to estimating that (in two *separate* steps) differ from how it is normally done (I assume on one step / in one model)?

Comment: I should clarify my comment, thanks. The 0-inflated poisson is superior to your method because it accounts for which proportion of observed 0 counts are due to not having a count, versus having a count which is 0. There is always a non-zero probability that a poisson process generates a 0 count. The 0-inf Poisson uses the EM algorithm to iteratively estimate the Binomial proportion of 0s and the lambda rate by which counts are produced.  If you used your method, a reviewer or tester would certainly ask why you didn't just use a 0-inflated poisson model.

Comment: Sounds a bit like a two part model.

Comment: The two-step approach is called a [hurdle model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81457/what-is-the-difference-between-zero-inflated-and-hurdle-distributions-models). They are not uncommon in my field (ecology). And it's not really the same as a Poisson-bernoulli mixture (aka zero-inflated model).

Comment: ... and I should note, that in a hurdle model the Poisson distribution is truncated so that the minimum observable value is 1.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution would be to use Generalized Additive Models for Location, Scale and Shape. There is a R-package `gamlss` with plenty of documentation available online. There are a [manual](http://www.gamlss.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/gamlss-manual.pdf), a [book](http://www.gamlss.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/book-2010-Athens1.pdf) and a [website](http://www.gamlss.org/).

In the R-package, you can include random effects as available in the package `lme4` using the function `gamlss::re()` and you have the two most common options of distribution for zero-inflated count data:  Zero-Inflated Poisson and Zero-Inflated Negative Binomial (when Var > Mean).

You also have the Zero-Altered Poisson, Zero-Altered Negative Binomial, and Zero-Altered Logarithmic models that are called Hurdle models.

Thus, if you do not have a strong reason to choose a Zero-Altered Poisson (approach suggest by you), you could fit all these options and find the most appropriate model for your data.