# Very skewed and zero-inflated continuous outcome variable

Tags: generalized-linear-model, dataset, continuous-data, zero-inflation

I am trying to predict a positive and continuous outcome by using the generalized linear model in R (glm function) and I am wondering what family could I use for the training data. Some of the families take the log of the outcome variable (if i understand this correctly) and the log of zero is -Inf. Note that almost the 80% of the outcomes are zero.

Here is what the outcome variable looks like

[image: Outcome Variable histogram]

Comment: I have a similar case, can you let us know how you did it in the end?

Answer (score 3):

I would not use *any* of the distributions available in GLM if I had an outcome variable like this. You need to widen your arsenal of methods. Consider e.g. a hurdle model or a zero inflated model (see [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81457/what-is-the-difference-between-zero-inflated-and-hurdle-models) for some good discussion). Although the zero-inflated-normal is less common that zero inflated count models, it does exist.

For a review of methods that have been tried, see [Min and Agresti (2002) *Modeling nonnegative data with clumping at zero*](http://users.stat.ufl.edu/~aa/articles/min_agresti_2002.pdf) . Methods they discuss include:

1. Tobit regression
2. Two part models
3. Sample selection models
4. Compound Poisson exponential dispersion models
5. Ordinal threshold models

A more recent paper is by [Eggers (2015)](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:816639/FULLTEXT01.pdf) *On statistical methods for zero-inflated models*. She covers:

1. Tobit models
2. Sample selection models
3. Double hurdle models
4. Two part models