# Distribution to use in a regression with a positive skewed variable with many zeros (homicide rates)

Tags: regression, skewness, zero-inflation

I want to study the determinants of homicide rates. However, I see when exploring the data that my dependent variable (homicide rates) has many zeros and is positive skewed. Which distribution family / approach should I use?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, these types of data can be analyzed using either via hurdle modelling or via zero-inflated modelling.

Which type of modelling you would use is a function of whether you can assume that there is only one process by which a zero rate can be produced (in which case you would use hurdle modelling), or that there are are two different processes that can produce a zero (in which case you would use zero-inflated modelling). See this  link to this Cross Validated post for further details: [What is the difference between zero-inflated and hurdle models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81457/what-is-the-difference-between-zero-inflated-and-hurdle-models).