# Using binary dummy to control excess of zeros in continuous data

Tags: regression, modeling, zero-inflation

I'm running an OLS and one of the explanatory variables accounts the sewage coverage, which is zero in 42% of the observations (these are true zeros). I'm worried that the linear effect is not going to be captured very well. Does it make sense to insert a dummy in the model that equals 1 if the sewage coverage is nonexistent and 0 if it exists?

Comment: I would change your modeling setup and run a 2-stage model. Check this answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/571172/32477

Comment: @Stefan the 0 values here seem to be in a predictor rather than the outcome.

Comment: @Edm Right, thanks for pointing this out! I misread it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reasonable way to proceed if you know that these are true 0 values that make the corresponding continuous value meaningless. This [answer from @whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/6565/28500) illustrates how to proceed in such a situation, where loan values are used as continuous predictors but are necessarily 0 if there is no loan at all. In this scenario, it might be easier to interpret the results if you do this with a reversal of your dummy variable.

If these are true 0 values on a continuous scale with actual values near 0, then it might make more sense to use a flexible regression spline or generalized additive model to capture the potential nonlinearity.

If these aren't true 0 values but represent values below some detection limit, see [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/482079/28500) for suggestions on how to handle left-censored *predictor* variables.

Comment: The cities that have sewage coverage in the dataset have inputs ranging from >0 to 100. Just to be certain, can you explain a bit more  about what you mean with "make the corresponding continuous value meaningless"?  Also, does the interpretation of the coeffcient on the continuous variable remains the same?

Comment: @llb1706 see the linked answer on loan values: if there's no loan, then loan value is essentially meaningless. If "nonexistent" coverage means a city without a sewer system, then it's meaningless to discuss how much its sewage system covers. If you set your dummy to 0 for "nonexistent" sewage coverage, then the intercept represents a situation with "nonexistent" sewage coverage. The sum of the intercept and the dummy coefficient is the extrapolation to 0 coverage among cities with sewer systems. The slope for coverage is the extra outcome per unit increase in coverage, for cities with sewers.

Comment: So it might be better to set the dummy to zero where sewage coverage is nonexistent, and to 1 if it exists. Thanks!