Selecting statistical test for significant difference between groups from count data with zero values
I wish test significant difference between groups from count data with zero values. I only want to compare groups with the same color (grey, yellow and blue). Some groups have only zero values which was expected, but unexpected for other groups. Other groups again have some unexpected zero values. Due to the zero values, I cannot use ANOVA test. I have come to learn that I should therefore instead apply either poisson, negative binomial, zero-inflated poisson or zero-inflated nagative binomial models. However, I am having troubles figuring out how to determine which model to apply. 
The counts are different bacteria (bac_1, bac_2 and bac_3) collected from faeces of animals after the animals were fed bacteria at the beginning of the experiment. Counts are therefore given as count/gram faeces. Zero counts can therefore be the results of bacteria not growing in the animal from the beginning or from cessation of growth by the time of collection. Some of the groups have received an identical treatment to their feed.
The figure displays log transformed data for the sake of visualisation.
Data for blue groups (bac_1) subset and including non-transformed counts:
bac_1 <- structure(list(d35_inoculum = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), 
    d35_treatment = c("no_tret", "no_tret", "no_tret", "no_tret", 
    "no_tret", "no_tret", "no_tret", "no_tret", "no_tret", "no_tret", 
    "no_tret", "no_tret", "treat", "treat", "treat", "treat", 
    "treat", "treat", "treat", "treat", "treat", "treat", "treat", 
    "treat", "no_tret", "no_tret", "no_tret", "no_tret", "no_tret", 
    "no_tret", "no_tret", "no_tret", "no_tret", "no_tret", "no_tret", 
    "no_tret", "treat", "treat", "treat", "treat", "treat", "treat", 
    "treat", "treat", "treat", "treat", "treat", "treat", "no_tret", 
    "no_tret", "no_tret", "no_tret", "no_tret", "no_tret", "no_tret", 
    "no_tret", "no_tret", "no_tret", "no_tret", "no_tret", "treat", 
    "treat", "treat", "treat", "treat", "treat", "treat", "treat", 
    "treat", "treat", "treat", "treat", "treat_1", "treat_1", 
    "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", 
    "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_2", "treat_2", 
    "treat_2", "treat_2", "treat_2", "treat_2", "treat_2", "treat_2", 
    "treat_2", "treat_2", "treat_2", "treat_2"), d35_id = c("1_1", 
    "1_2", "1_3", "1_4", "1_5", "1_6", "1_7", "1_8", "1_9", "1_10", 
    "1_11", "1_12", "2_16", "2_17", "2_18", "2_19", "2_20", "2_21", 
    "2_22", "2_23", "2_24", "2_25", "2_26", "2_27", "3_31", "3_32", 
    "3_33", "3_34", "3_35", "3_36", "3_37", "3_38", "3_39", "3_40", 
    "3_41", "3_42", "4_46", "4_47", "4_48", "4_49", "4_50", "4_51", 
    "4_52", "4_53", "4_54", "4_55", "4_56", "4_57", "5_61", "5_62", 
    "5_63", "5_64", "5_65", "5_66", "5_67", "5_68", "5_69", "5_70", 
    "5_71", "5_72", "6_76", "6_77", "6_78", "6_79", "6_80", "6_81", 
    "6_82", "6_83", "6_84", "6_85", "6_86", "6_87", "7_91", "7_92", 
    "7_93", "7_94", "7_95", "7_96", "7_97", "7_98", "7_99", "7_100", 
    "7_101", "7_102", "8_106", "8_107", "8_108", "8_109", "8_110", 
    "8_111", "8_112", "8_113", "8_114", "8_115", "8_116", "8_117"
    ), d35_ce_group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), bact = c("bac_1", 
    "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", 
    "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", 
    "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", 
    "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", 
    "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", 
    "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", 
    "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", 
    "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", 
    "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", 
    "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", 
    "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", 
    "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", 
    "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", 
    "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1", "bac_1"), CFU_g = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 16400L, 65300L, 5000L, 47000L, 4220L, 
    43900L, 10000L, 2500L, 1670L, 1000L, 1100L, 7500L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 53600L, 14500L, 0L, 
    33400L, 21400L, 36700L, 16500L, 25000L, 0L, 104000L, 55300L, 
    28300L, 1770000L, 720000L, 63200L, 1900000L, 270000L, 70300L, 
    3540000L, 115000L, 69700L, 90000L, 193000L, 1190000L, 147000L, 
    44300L, 108000L, 150000L, 133000L, 60000L, 57000L, 40900L, 
    20000L, 50000L, 153000L, 81700L, 23700L, 4500L, 16700L, 4250L, 
    4380L, 1070L, 1270L, 11600L, 6620L, 16000L, 6430L, 14800L
    ), CFU_g_log = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.21487032861122, 4.81491983198191, 
    3.69905685454767, 4.67210709814554, 3.62541535215441, 4.64247441294225, 
    4.00004342727686, 3.3981136917305, 3.22297644989339, 3.00043407747932, 
    3.04178731897175, 3.87511916546257, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.72917289212618, 4.1613979525458, 0, 4.52375946944571, 
    4.33043406700971, 4.56467789772798, 4.21751026429403, 4.39795738010389, 
    0, 5.01703751518718, 4.74273298466013, 4.45180178134793, 
    6.24797351172585, 5.85733309961763, 4.80072394997615, 6.27875382952881, 
    5.43136537265409, 4.84696150270678, 6.54900338470783, 5.06070161681095, 
    4.8432390089641, 4.95424733490676, 5.28555955923242, 6.07554732634572, 
    5.16732028912236, 4.6464135295996, 5.03342777671354, 5.17609415434258, 
    5.12385490632685, 4.77815848856469, 4.75588247480709, 4.61173392632452, 
    4.30105170984523, 4.6989786901388, 5.18469426933435, 4.91222737222182, 
    4.3747666702852, 3.65330901293848, 4.2227424760266, 3.62849110496712, 
    3.64157325317818, 3.02978947083186, 3.10414555055401, 4.06449542679273, 
    3.82092358788132, 4.20414712521285, 3.80827850958277, 4.17029105862539
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -96L))


Please link to the data! Are the zero values of the logs or the values themselves?

One solution commonly suggested here is to use square roots instead of logs in cases where there are zeroes (and cube roots if there are negative values). But the best solution depends on your goals - you may not need any transformation if you're simply aiming to compare groups.

@kjetilbhalvorsen. I could not find a function for adding data. How can I link to data? The untransformed values had zeroes. So, I added 1 to the untransformed data, so that I could log transform. Hope this answers you question.

@mkt I did the transformation only because it improved the visualisation of the data.

Never mind, given the distributions in your plot, simply choosing a different transformation alone won't help. Have you looked at our threads on zero inflation? Click the tag you used to see them. This may be a good place to start: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81457/what-is-the-difference-between-zero-inflated-and-hurdle-models

@mkt Thanks for the link to the tread. I am not sure whether to consider the zero values to come from one or two different processes though. A value can be zero in the absence of bacterial growth, but can also be zero if bacteria present at an earlier time point has ceased to grow.

@kjetilbhalvorsen I finally figured out how to include data.

It's not completely clear to me what the statement "can also be zero if bacteria present at an earlier time point has ceased to grow" means in terms of your experimental design. In my experience, CFU assays start with a sterile plate onto which you distribute bacteria under specified conditions, so it's not clear where those "bacteria present at an earlier time point" come from. Please edit the question to say more about the underlying experimental design.

Two other things that would be good to include when you edit the question. First, it seems that the CFU values were already scaled or normalized in some way before you did the log(CFU+1) transformation. If you are using Poisson or negative binomial models, you need to start with the actual original counts. Second, it's not clear whether "treat" means the same thing across inocula A, B and C.

Presumably by "means" you are referring to the expected logarithms of the underlying distributions.  The expected logarithm of any distribution assigning nonzero probability to the value $0$ is negative infinity.  This causes me to suspect you haven't framed your underlying question in a useful way.  But what do you really want to learn or demonstrate?

@EdM I have edited the question with a brief description of experimental setup and also included non-transformed count data.

@whuber I want to demonstrate which groups are significantly different from other groups.

Thanks for editing the question. The CFU_g values still seem to be normalized (possibly by gram animal body weight), however, so they can't be used directly in a Poisson or negative binomial model. Use the original raw counts as the outcome values and then include an offset term in the model to deal with the per gram (or whatever) normalization. In your situation I suspect that would be log(body_weight). Also, use natural logs rather than base-10 logs when you set up the model.

Okay, but for that purpose the zeros wouldn't be any problem.

@EdM. The counts are given per gram of the faeces from which the bacteria were collected. Each count there comes from a different value of the denominator. So, does it still make sense to use the raw count?

$\log_{10}($value$\ + 1)$ has a little rationale (chiefly simplicity) when values are counts; it has less rationale when values are measured with units. In essence, you need to justify the choice of $1$ and compare results with those from other choices of the fudge constant.

@NickCox I used log10( value +1) on the data just for the sake a visualisation, and it has been suggested above that I could use square root instead.  I don't necessarily intend to do the statistics on the transformed values.

Working on transformed scale doesn’t necessarily mean transformation; it could mean using a generalized linear model. Using the raw data is likely to be even more problematic!

Thanks for posting your data. What can be seen on your graph (roughly) is that the smallest observed outcome is about 1000, In fact it is exactly 1000. The largest observed value is 3540000. Hence log1p() (which is a function in many languages) maps (0, 1000, 3540000) to (rounding a little) (0, 6.91, 15.08). So, the transformation pulls in high outliers while also making all the zeros outliers. Is this scientifically realistic? Other way round, cube roots don't seem to help much.

Smallest means smallest positive above.

A Poisson or negative binomial model for counts is a generalized linear model that uses a link function between a linear predictor (inoculum/treatment combinations, in your data) and the observed count outcome. The default for count models is a (natural) log link, so that you are modeling the log of the mean counts for each treatment. That's different from modeling the mean of (more-or-less) log-transformed counts, which is what you would be doing if you continued trying to analyze the log(CFU_g +1) values displayed in the plot.
These generalized linear models use the actual observed number of counts. You use an offset term in the model to normalize for the scale over which the counts were observed (grams of feces in your case). That's a better way to accomplish what you were trying to do by dividing the number of bacterial colony forming units (CFU) by the grams of feces collected. For example, if you had instead divided by the number of milligrams of feces and plotted log(CFU_mg +1), the wide gap between the zero-count values and non-zero values would have been much less. Using a count-appropriate generalized linear model with an offset avoids that type of arbitrary result.
If you have a low but non-zero number of mean counts, you should expect some individual zero-count observations. Once you get back to the original counts and use a generalized linear model with an offset, you thus might not need a zero-inflated or hurdle model for bacterial strains 2 and 3. Even a Poisson model might work for each of those strains, for example:
modelBac2 <- glm(CFU ~ treatment + log(feces_weight), data = bacterium2, family = poisson)

where CFU is the actual number of CFU, treatment is a categorical predictor representing the treatment/inoculum combination and log(feces_weight) is the offset that normalizes for the weight of feces collected. The log() transformation (natural log is the default in R) corresponds with the default log link of a Poisson model. If a Poisson model isn't sufficient you could consider a negative binomial model, or a "quasi-Poisson" model relaxing the Poisson assumption that the variance among observations is the mean number of counts per observation.
Bacterial strain 1 has some inoculum/treatment combinations with all observed counts of zero: both treatments for Inoculum A, and treat treatment for Inoculum B. If you want to do a comprehensive model of that strain across all inocula, you might need to use a zero-inflated or hurdle model that combines the probability of having any counts with an appropriate model for the number of counts if there are any at all. Based on your understanding of the subject matter and details of your experimental design (for example, it's not clear what the different inocula represent or why there are more treatments for Inoculum C than for the others), it might make more sense to evaluate each inoculum separately for that strain.
One more thing to consider: if any animals were used for more than one inoculum/treatment combination, then you need to take into account the lack of independence among the observations on that animal. That can be done with a generalized linear mixed model that allows for "random effects" associated with each animal.

Thank you so much EdM. This was extremely useful for me.
